# How to do a query every minutes in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, schedule

I'm new to laravel scheduler system.
I'm using laravel 8.
I have read the documentation of laravel about the kernel.php file.

Here is my schedule method

```
namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
   /**
   * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
   *
   * @var array
   */
   protected $commands = [
      //
   ];

   /**
   * Define the application's command schedule.
   *
   * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
   * @return void
   */
   protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
   {
      $schedule->call(function () {
         DB::table('verifications')->truncate();
      })->everyMinute();
   }

   /**
   * Register the commands for the application.
   *
   * @return void
   */
   protected function commands()
   {
      $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

      require base_path('routes/console.php');
   }
}
```

but it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: What "_doesn't work correctly_"? Wrong job run? Wrong table truncated? Did you set up a cronjob for your project?

Comment: I didn't set a cronjob for my project.  How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run crontab which will be executing your laraver scheduler every minute

Comment: thanks for your answer,   but I didn't get what you mean.  can you please explain more ?

Answer (score 0):

schedule() is a function to put together all cron job you need.
but you still have to run this function with a command, if you are in locally just ***run php artisan schedule:work***
and if you aren't in local need to create a cron job to run this command for you!
I hope it is useful!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a [cronjob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) that runs the Laravel scheduler. The scheduler is run every minute and determines which command to run at what time.

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

The manual: [Running The Scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler)

Edit: this mostly applies to the Linux/Unix OS, for Windows I *think* you can set up the Windows scheduler, but I am not proficient with that

Edit2: To test your schedules locally without setting up a cronjob you can run `php artisan schedule:work` as stated in [Running The Scheduler Locally](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler-locally)